# Is there a way to create all relationships in single create call in a many-to-many relationship considering unique attribute in one of the entities?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, mysql2

Suppose the following example:

We have three models: News, Tag, NewsTags

```
// News Model
const News = sequelize.define("News", {
  title: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
  content: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
});

News.associate = function ({ Tag, NewsTags }) {
  News.belongsToMany(Tag, { through: NewsTags });
};

// Tag Model
const Tag = sequelize.define("Tag", {
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true },
});

Tag.associate = function ({ News, NewsTags }) {
  Tag.belongsToMany(News, { through: NewsTags });
};

// NewsTags Model
const NewsTags = sequelize.define("NewsTags");

NewsTags.associate = function ({ News, Tag }) {
  NewsTags.belongsTo(News);
  NewsTags.belongsTo(Tag);
};
```

**Note: Tag name is unique**

When creating news, I want to check if a tag already exists, then don't violate the unique constraint and add new record only in NewsTags

I tried the following snippet:

```
const news = await News.create({
  title: "test"
  content: "bla bla bla...",
  Tags: [{ name: 'politics' }, { name: 'economics' }, { name: 'sports' }]
}, {
  include: Tag
});
```

Assume the three tables are empty and we add a news, the above will execute as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `News` (`id`,`title`,`content`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);
INSERT INTO `Tags` (`id`,`name`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (?,?,?,?);
INSERT INTO `Tags` (`id`,`name`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (?,?,?,?);
INSERT INTO `Tags` (`id`,`name`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (?,?,?,?);
INSERT INTO `NewsTags` (`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`NewsId`,`TagId`) VALUES (?,?,?,?);
INSERT INTO `NewsTags` (`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`NewsId`,`TagId`) VALUES (?,?,?,?);
INSERT INTO `NewsTags` (`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`NewsId`,`TagId`) VALUES (?,?,?,?);
```

If another news was added with the same tags, it will execute as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `News` (`id`,`title`,`content`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

And my expected result is

```
INSERT INTO `News` (`id`,`title`,`content`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);
INSERT INTO `NewsTags` (`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`NewsId`,`TagId`) VALUES (?,?,?,?);
INSERT INTO `NewsTags` (`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`NewsId`,`TagId`) VALUES (?,?,?,?);
INSERT INTO `NewsTags` (`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`NewsId`,`TagId`) VALUES (?,?,?,?);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear to me, since it initially asks about creating "all relationships in a single create call", but then it looks like it's actually asking about how to avoid a 'duplicate insert' error (you say "check if a tag already exists, then don't violate the unique constraint").
If you're asking about avoiding the 'duplicate' error and if you need to be truly database-agnostic, then the simplest way I can  think of is to do a SELECT from your Tags table to see if the Tag already exists before you do the INSERT.

Comment: I was trying to find a way to SELECT, CHECK & INSERT, according to the selection, either to insert in the News and NewsTags, or to insert in all the entities.


I.e: when adding a new news -which include title, content and optional tag(s)-, first I want Sequelize to check if the tag already exists, then add record only in the News and NewsTags, on the other side, when posting a new tag with the news, then add in three models (News, Tag and NewsTags)

Comment: I'm aware of that, I understand. But it seems like you're wanting all that to happen in one "magic" command, something to do all the work for you without your code having to deal with it. I don't know anything about "Sequelize" except that it's yet another ORM, but I'm not confident you're going to find a "magic" command to do all that in this ORM. You COULD use a 'raw' query and probably accomplish it with that.